# SQL return wrong result

Tags: sql

It's looks I missed with operator priority. Here is my request:

```
SELECT
        "id",
        "arch_date2",
        "ftp_file_full_path",
        "isProcessing",
        "processing_status",
        "region",
        "isUnpacked",
        "section_name"
    FROM "ftp_files" WHERE "isUnpacked" IS NULL 
        AND "section_name" IN ('protocols','notifications','contracts')  
        AND ("region" = 'Chechenskaja_Resp' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01')  
        OR ("region" = 'Arkhangelskaja_obl' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01')  
        OR ("region" = 'Astrakhanskaja_obl' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01')  
        OR ("region" = 'Bajkonur_g' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01')  
        order by "region" LIMIT 1;
```

But in result I am getting row with `isUnpacked='True'`

[image]

Comment: You probably want to add parentheses around the whole sections part in the WHERE clause.

Comment: If any of the OR clauses is true then the result is true

Comment: Brackets issue, you have conditions X and Y or Z.. put  all the `region` conditions in brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses around the whole regions part in the `WHERE` clause:

```
FROM "ftp_files" WHERE "isUnpacked" IS NULL 
    AND "section_name" IN ('protocols','notifications','contracts')  
    AND (("region" = 'Chechenskaja_Resp' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01')  
      OR ("region" = 'Arkhangelskaja_obl' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arc h_date2<='2019-01-01')  
      OR ("region" = 'Astrakhanskaja_obl' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01')  
      OR ("region" = 'Bajkonur_g' AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01'))
    order by "region" LIMIT 1;
```

Or simplify as:

```
FROM "ftp_files" WHERE "isUnpacked" IS NULL 
    AND "section_name" IN ('protocols','notifications','contracts')  
    AND "region" IN ('Chechenskaja_Resp', 'Arkhangelskaja_obl',
                     'Astrakhanskaja_obl', 'Bajkonur_g')
    AND arch_date2>='2018-01-01' AND arch_date2<='2019-01-01'
order by "region" LIMIT 1;
```